# Why i get a duplicate output when the loop if there is a scanf?

Tags: for-loop, go

When the user enters a wrong number, the code expects to show once the output message but this it's duplicated. why?

note: seems to be something with the scanf inside the loop because if I use scan lonely it works as expected.

Anyway, I can't understand why this behavior

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "math/rand"
  "time"
)

func main(){
  rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

  var number int = rand.Intn(99)  
  var input int = 0

  fmt.Println("random: ", number)

  fmt.Println("enter a number: ")
  fmt.Scanf("%d",&input)

  for {
    if number != input {
      fmt.Println("wrong! try again:")
      fmt.Scanf("%d",&input)
      continue
    } else {
      fmt.Println("that's correct!")
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: yes, but a friend reported to me the same issue on linux.

Comment: @Poyo: It works on Linux: `go version devel +d47526ed77 Sat Aug 31 01:06:32 2019 +0000 linux/amd64`. There are known issues on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomodate Windows, write `fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &input)`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    var number int = rand.Intn(99)
    var input int = 0

    fmt.Println("random: ", number)

    fmt.Println("enter a number: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &input)

    for {
        if number != input {
            fmt.Println("wrong! try again:")
            fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &input)
            continue
        } else {
            fmt.Println("that's correct!")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
random:  84
enter a number: 
42
wrong! try again:
42
wrong! try again:
84
that's correct!
```

---

Windows uses `"\r\n"` for end-of-line. Linux and others use `"\n"` for end-of-line.

You did not check for `Scanf` errors.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    var number int = rand.Intn(99)
    var input int = 0

    fmt.Println("random: ", number)

    fmt.Println("enter a number: ")
    n, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &input)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(n, err)
    }

    for {
        if number != input {
            fmt.Println("wrong! try again:")
            n, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &input)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(n, err)
            }
            continue
        } else {
            fmt.Println("that's correct!")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Output (Windows):

```
random:  84
enter a number:
42
wrong! try again:
0 unexpected newline
wrong! try again:
42
wrong! try again:
0 unexpected newline
wrong! try again:
84
that's correct!
```

Windows Scans `"42\r\n"` as `"42\r"` and `"\n"`.

Output (Linux):

```
random:  84
enter a number: 
42
wrong! try again:
42
wrong! try again:
84
that's correct!
```

Linux Scans `"42\n"`.

Comment: Well, your example is incorrect. It duplicates output,: https://onlinegdb.com/ZeL2m2-na The same behaviour is under Windows.

Answer (score -1):

`fmt.Scanf` will read input alongside the format, if the format doesn't match then the next rune (char) will pass to next input as parameter.

for instance if you have input like `abc` and you have code like:

```golang
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &input)
    // will return 1 error when if failed to parse "a" as integer 
    // and pass "bc" to next input
    // but no other fmt.Scanf so nothing else to be feed with "bc"
```

and with same input you have the following code:

```golang
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &input) 
    // input = 0; error failed to parse "a" as integer 
    // and pass "bc" to next input as parameter

    for {
      if number != input {
        fmt.Println("wrong! try again:")
        fmt.Scanf("%d",&input) 
        // input = 0; error 3 times as 
        // failed to parse "b", "c" as integer
        // and unexpected new line

        continue
      } else {
        fmt.Println("that's correct!")
        break
      }
    }
```

hopefully it helps.

ref: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf